# how return array objects in find mongodb hierarchy data json

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, mongodb

How to return the array object "items" as follows database db.customers using mongodb

I have problems when going to another page because the query returns me a single object, not the object array items

```
Customer
        .find({user: req.user})
        .filter(filter)
        .order(sort)
        .map(function(doc){
              return doc.get('videos').items;
            })
        .page(pagination, function(err, customers){
                if(err){
                    return res.status(400).send({
                        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                    });
                } else{

                res.jsonp(customers);
                }
            });
```

below the json structure where is the array items:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("54de533a9585180c24f42887"),
  "videos" : {
    "items" : [{
        "snippet" : {
          "liveBroadcastContent" : "none",
          "thumbnails" : {

            "default" : {
              "height" : 90,
              "width" : 120,
              "url" : "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xLWBnEQQiIA/default.jpg"
            }
          },
          "description" : "yea  foodporn",
          "title" : "#foodporn",
          "channelId" : "UC7FN6ofleSjbqwWxt-FNDWQ",
          "publishedAt" : "2015-01-16T03:21:35.000Z"
        },
        "id" : {
          "videoId" : "xLWBnEQQiIA",
          "kind" : "youtube#video"
        },
        "etag" : "\"k1sYjErg4tK7WaQQxvJkW5fVrfg/M4htbh5SyAjA8ul83DhltycTU6E\"",
        "kind" : "youtube#searchResult"
      }, {
        "snippet" : {
          "liveBroadcastContent" : "none",
          "thumbnails" : {

            "default" : {
              "height" : 90,
              "width" : 120,
              "url" : "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/v-1_pxe37-s/default.jpg"
            }
          },
          "description" : "food porn delicius",
          "title" : "#foodporn b",
          "channelId" : "UC7FN6ofleSjbqwWxt-FNDWQ",
          "publishedAt" : "2015-01-16T03:14:15.000Z"
        },
        "id" : {
          "videoId" : "v-1_pxe37-s",
          "kind" : "youtube#video"
        },
        "etag" : "\"k1sYjErg4tK7WaQQxvJkW5fVrfg/0SfjWbYvc4M7hdvXUFAsnZF-3vU\"",
        "kind" : "youtube#searchResult"
      }, {
        "snippet" : {
          "liveBroadcastContent" : "none",
          "thumbnails" : {

            "default" : {
              "height" : 90,
              "width" : 120,
              "url" : "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DMfa1u8_3B8/default.jpg"
            }
          },
          "description" : "o yeah foos porn",
          "title" : "food porn a",
          "channelId" : "UC7FN6ofleSjbqwWxt-FNDWQ",
          "publishedAt" : "2015-01-16T03:03:09.000Z"
        },
        "id" : {
          "videoId" : "DMfa1u8_3B8",
          "kind" : "youtube#video"
        },
        "etag" : "\"k1sYjErg4tK7WaQQxvJkW5fVrfg/ghsCGgrP3VQw6kH3v2LijEPPUv8\"",
        "kind" : "youtube#searchResult"
      }],
    "pageInfo" : {
      "resultsPerPage" : 50,
      "totalResults" : 30
    },
    "nextPageToken" : "Cib3_b-JoP____96V0dSU3BHYjlCRQD_Af_-eldHUlNwR2I5QkUAARAeIbnxc1PpBEevOQAAAABfdkACSAFQAFoLCSuH7BJBzCiDEAE=",
    "etag" : "\"k1sYjErg4tK7WaQQxvJkW5fVrfg/WBVbC5oh7cdDE3IlyjlCZpMW7bQ\"",
    "kind" : "youtube#searchListResponse"
  },
  "user" : ObjectId("54de0f96b4d42d90195f892e"),
  "__v" : 0
}
  "user" : ObjectId("54de0f96b4d42d90195f892e"),
  "__v" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Customer.find(...).map(function(doc){
  return doc.get('videos').items;
})
```

This what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I think the call you're looking for is

```
db.customers.find({ "user" : "xxx" }, { "videos.items" : 1 })
```

See the [projection docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) for more information about how to return specific fields from documents in a query.